# Laravel 5 Auth active members

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

There are several similar questions but all of them seem incomplete as they are referring to not existing functions.

I am referring to:

[Check for active user state with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750375/check-for-active-user-state-with-laravel)

[Login only if user is active using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015606/login-only-if-user-is-active-using-laravel)

[extend laravel 5 built-in authentication to login only "if user == active"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244748/extend-laravel-5-built-in-authentication-to-login-only-if-user-active?lq=1)

In all of them there are presented solutions mostly to alter functions from `AuthController`, however those functions are not there.

I am using latest version of Laravel (5.2) so my default mentioned file looks like: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

Now, how do I implement this functionality? I have tried copying `public function postLogin()` (as suggested in those other mentioned posts) into that `AuthController` file. Nothing changed.

I am clearly missing something here.

Please someone help!

Edit: 
The function that I have added is:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
]);

$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

// This section is the only change
if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
    $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
    if ($user->active) {
        Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    } else {
        return redirect($this->loginPath()) // Change this to redirect elsewhere
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'active' => 'You must be active to login.'
            ]);
    }
}

return redirect($this->loginPath())
    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
    ->withErrors([
        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
    ]);

}
```

Comment: If you are using `Route::auth()` to register the routes for Auth the method isn't `postLogin` its `login`, check your routes.

Comment: Ok, I have renamed the function from `postLogin` to `login`. I had an exception raised about `Request` and I had to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request`. Now I get another exception: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found`

Comment: That is a PHP namespacing issue.

Comment: that is triggered on this line: `if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {` from the code written in the question. It's like I could not use the facade here.

Comment: It is a namespacing issue. You have to instruct PHP that class isn't in the current namespace. If you need a brief introduction to namespacing check out this article: [https://mattstauffer.co/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-php-namespacing](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-php-namespacing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for everyone facing the same problem on Laravel 5.2 with Authentication provided by `php artisan make:auth`.

First important thing is to understand that `Route::auth();`  points to `login` function and not `postLogin`(Thank you @lagbox!)

Then you will have to update `AuthController`:

Add on top of the file:

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Add somewhere after `use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;` :

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users if login is unsuccessufull.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $loginPath = '/login';`
```

And the updated `login` function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
]);

$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

// This section is the only change
if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
    $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
    if ($user->active) {
        Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    } else {
        return redirect($this->loginPath) // Change this to redirect elsewhere
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'active' => 'You must be active to login.'
            ]);
    }
}

return redirect($this->loginPath)
    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
    ->withErrors([
        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
    ]);

}
```

Then `login.blade.php` should be updated to show the new error `@if ($errors->has('active'))`

Thank you guys for help!

Comment: I just wanted to add that in Laravel 5.1 it's `postLogin`

Answer (score 1):

Most functionality in `AuthController` is added using [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Note this line in the beginning of the class:

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

If you look at [AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php) you can see that it does have a postLogin method.

As of why implementing this method doesn't work: I think you are missing the `$request` parameter in the method signature.

Add a larger code snippet to your question if this isn't the case.

EDIT: for future debugging: `php artisan route:list` gives you a list of which routes call which methods. This can give you a hint to which method to override.

Comment: So you are saying that I should instead update the function from [AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php) ?

Comment: No, you should override it in `AuthController` (it should be possible). `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` is located somewhere in your vendor directory which you shouldn't touch because changes are overriden by composer in no time. `AuthController` is a nice class in your project's Controllers directory which I think is intended for this kind of adaptions. Just copy the method signature (or maybe the whole method) from `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`.

Comment: Exactly! I have updated my question with the function I have added. Besides that I have added `Use Request;` on the top of the `AuthController` file. Still didn't figured out why isn't working.

Comment: dont add `use Request` that is the facade, not the actual request class.

Comment: With or without `Use Request`, it's still not working. And also no exceptions are raised.

Comment: Are you saying that you also don't have any exceptions without the `use Request;`? That seems weird. Anyway, instead of the facade, use `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` instead.

Comment: As @lagbox suggested, I had to change the function name from `postLogin` to `login`. Then I had the exception about Request, and I have added `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`. Now I have another exception about Auth.